# How to combine two strings using Stack's push and pop operations?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

If I have two strings say `str1 & str2`

```
str1 = I to cricket chess 

str2 = like play and
```

I want the output as :

"I like to play cricket and chess"

Can this be done using `push` and `pop` operations of `stack`.
Algorithm should be independent of programming language. Strings mentioned above can
be of any length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple. You just need to `push` first word from the first string to the stack, then `push` the first word from the second string, then do the same for second words, then to third words etc.

After that, you need to `pop` each element from the stack and `push` it to the second stack, to invert sequence. Then you just `pop` each element from the second stack and add it to the result string.

Comment: I would say this is a better solution than mine, as you don't have to maintain two separate indexes to decrement, which could be error prone. I wager mine is more time and space efficient (no second stack, and no double traversal of the stack), at the expense of being more error prone.

Comment: Yes, but if you use queue, not the stack, it is possible to omit the second phase.

Comment: A queue would make this trivial. I think the whole idea is to test the OP's understanding of the nature of a LIFO, while dealing with the FIFO nature of parsing a sentence (even if it's split between two strings).

Answer (score 1):

From what you've given, you have to make some assumptions.

Assumptions:

1. Words in the sentence are interleaved between both strings
2. One string will be at most one word longer than the other string
3. Space is the separator for words.

The algorithm would be as such:

1. For each string:
2. split the string up into an array, on the space character
3. Find the array with the longest length
4. Starting with the array from the longest length (call this arrayB, and the other arrayO)
5. From the end of the array,
6. push the element of arrayB onto the stack,
7. push the element of arrayO onto the stack,
8. Repeat until all elements in each array are pushed, alternating between the two arrays.
9. When finished, pop the stack into an array,
10. Join the array into a string, using a space as the separator.